# 'Add Modifiers' Button not appearing

Tags: modifiers, error

I've been working on a model today, and all of a sudden the 'add modifiers' button has disappeared, as well as any other options on any of the other tabs. I don't remember hitting any random buttons, but this has kind of halted my progress. Any help is appreciated.

[image: error1] [image: error 2]

Comment: Seems to be a bug (that doesnt match the site guidelines), but it would be hard to report it as bug and let devs to check the issue from such a low amounth of info (also I'm not sure if there is happening any bug fixing for 2.79 version.

Comment: Might be worth restarting Blender?